# How to write custom exception with user defined fields?

Tags: java, exception

This might be an easy thing but I am just confused a bit. How to write a custom exception with user defined fields.

Lets take an example:

```
public class MyException extends Exception
{
public  MyException()
    {
        super();
    }

    public  MyException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }

    public MyException(String message, Throwable cause){
        super(message,cause);
    }
}
```

Now I want something like:

```
public MyException(String errCode, String message, Throwable cause){
        //Want to get same result as other constructor but with errCode field   
}
```

Just confused how to do this. Please help!

Comment: what is the confusion? just write the constructor and call the applicable super constructor. Save the errCode value in an instance variable of MyException

Comment: Well, an `Exception` is a class like any other... What problem do you have exactly?

Comment: append the error code to the message and call `super(message,cause);`?

Comment: @sidgate there is no applicable super constructor..

Comment: @Theolodis I would be needing it as seperate field.

Comment: @Nik then follow the solutions in the Answer section.

Comment: What if I also want to log this custom field, in case of the exception so that I immediately know what's is the value which cased it. e.g. InvalidPathException in java takes (input, cause) where input is the value of the path string.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    private String errCode;

    public MyException(String errCode, String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.errCode = errCode;
    }

    //getter, setter

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to hold the error code in your class as a member variable and then give a getter method on it.

```
private String errCode;

public MyException(String errCode, String message, Throwable cause){

      super(message, cause);  
      this.errCode = errCode
}

public String getErrCode() {
   return this.errCode;
 }
```

When you receive the exception object, you can call `getErrCode` method to get the error code

Answer (score 2):

the filed should be final. that is the correct way of doing it. like below

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

private final int status;

public MyException(String message, int status) {
    super(message);
    this.status = status;
}

public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyException extends Exception { 
    private String errCode;

public  MyException(){
    super();
}

public  MyException(String message){
    super(message);
}

public MyException(String message, Throwable cause){
    super(message,cause);
}

public MyException(String errCode, String message, Throwable cause){
        super(message,cause);
        this.errCode = errCode;  
}
public String getErrCode() {
   return this.errCode;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this for example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        try{
            testException(-5);
            testException(-10);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            System.out.println("Releasing resources");          
        }
        testException(15);
    }

    public static void testException(int i) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        if(i < 0){
            FileNotFoundException myException = new FileNotFoundException("Negative Integer "+i);
            throw myException;
        }else if(i > 10){
            throw new IOException("Only supported for index 0 to 10");
        }

    }
```

---

Or by creating custom class

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4664456874499611218L;

    private String errorCode="Unknown_Exception";

    public MyException(String message, String errorCode){
        super(message);
        this.errorCode=errorCode;
    }

    public String getErrorCode(){
        return this.errorCode;
    }


}
```

and then you can use it like

```
public class CustomExceptionExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MyException {
        try {
            processFile("file.txt");
        } catch (MyException e) {
            processErrorCodes(e);
        }

    }

    private static void processErrorCodes(MyException e) throws MyException {
        switch(e.getErrorCode()){
        case "BAD_FILE_TYPE":
            System.out.println("Bad File Type, notify user");
            throw e;
        case "FILE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION":
            System.out.println("File Not Found, notify user");
            throw e;
        case "FILE_CLOSE_EXCEPTION":
            System.out.println("File Close failed, just log it.");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Unknown exception occured, lets log it for further debugging."+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void processFile(String file) throws MyException {       
        InputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new MyException(e.getMessage(),"FILE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION");
        }finally{
            try {
                if(fis !=null)fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new MyException(e.getMessage(),"FILE_CLOSE_EXCEPTION");
            }
        }
    }

}
```